# Check Android App Size

Tags: android, size

I was wondering if there is a way to check the size of your app while you are in the development stages of your Android app rather then waiting until you finish the app and then create the apk.

Comment: If you're on Eclipse and have auto build enabled, you can look under the `/bin` folder, an apk should be there. You can check that.

Comment: Why? Concentrate on getting the app done first then worry about file size if its a concern, there's **proguard** that will shrink it down, if using pngs, the latest SDK crunches them down... or use [tinypng](http://tinypng.com) to compress them...

Comment: I wasn't worried about the size of my app. It was solely just to get an idea of how large it was cause I really had no idea whatsoever. Thank both of you for your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `.apk` file in the `bin` folder. Every time you run your application, it will generate a new `.apk` file.